# GCD in iOS not updating my label

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, mobile, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to update my custom label using GCD however all I am getting is the text I initialized the label with:

```
-(void)drawCardInfo{

    __block NSString *cardString;

    PPLinearLayoutLabelItem *cardDetails = [[PPLinearLayoutLabelItem alloc] initWithText:@"CREDIT CARD INFO" font:[PPFonts regular18] maxWidth:[LayoutValues getMaxWidthClipped]];
    [cardDetails setPaddingTop:20];
    [cardDetails setPaddingBottom:10];
    [self.topContainerContent addObject:cardDetails];

    PPLinearLayoutLabelItem *cardInfo = [[PPLinearLayoutLabelItem alloc] initWithText:@"Data" font:[PPFonts bold16] maxWidth:[LayoutValues getMaxWidthClipped]];
    [cardInfo setPaddingTop:0];
    [self.topContainerContent addObject:cardInfo];


    LinearLayoutHorizontalLine *line1 = [[LinearLayoutHorizontalLine alloc] initWithMaxWidth:[LayoutValues getMaxWidthClipped]];
    [self.topContainerContent addObject:line1];

    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{


        NSOperationQueue *networkQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        networkQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 5;
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]
                                             initWithRequest:request];
        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


            if([string isEqualToString:@""]){

            } else {

                NSMutableDictionary *dict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:kNilOptions error:nil];
                NSString *cardType = [dict objectForKey:@"credit_card_type"];
                NSString *cardFinalFour = [dict objectForKey:@"credit_card_last_4"];
                cardString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ **** %@",cardType, cardFinalFour];


                NSLog(@"%@",cardString);

            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [cardInfo setText:cardString]; });

        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"%s: AFHTTPRequestOperation error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
        }];

        [networkQueue addOperation:operation];

    });

}
```

I am successfully logging out the value proving that the network call works fine on a separate thread. Still my label is not being updated. How can I mitigate this?

Comment: Hi, the network operation you're performing itself is an async operation. You don't need to wrap it inside `dispatch_async`

Comment: Still does'nt work

Comment: Using iVars in multi threaded code is asking for trouble (and underscores are icky). Why aren't you using local variables?

Comment: Editing question.

Comment: @Ackman, try using block variables for cardString. i.e, `__block NSString *cardString`

Comment: How does that matter?

Comment: Made my edits to code and the post. Does anyone know whats going on?

Comment: Am I missing something here, or are you updating your UI in an async thread?

Comment: Well I am fairly new to iOS but can't you do that? Sorry, if I am missing something

Comment: Try this:      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      yourLabel.text = @"Yeah! Text Changed"; });

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to update the text for the label in a background thread. Updating UI elements on anywhere other than the main thread is not such a good idea since you never know when a asynchronous job will finish.

You can use the following ways to go about it:

1. Get the main thread and then update the text label

   ```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   //Code here to which needs to update the UI in the UI thread goes here

   });
   ```
2. Use `dispatch_sync`
3. Use `NSOperations` with dependancies (This will be the longest)

Comment: Where do I use dispatch_async?

Comment: Done. I have just updated code. Can you tell me what changes do i need to do?

Comment: All my UI generation is now on main thread. I call network on a separate thread. Where do I place code for async_dispatch once code commences? I mean where do I update label once thread finishes executing?

Comment: Do not use dispatch_sync (option 2) without checking whether you are actually on the main thread. That might result in a deadlock.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: You put the code in your completion handler. Just remember that "dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()" will queue your actions to be executed on the main thread. So you can put all UI actions in the main queue block inside your completion handler.

Comment: I have updated my code and I am logging out value in completion block and it's coming out okay. Done what you have said but still does not seem to work. Can you post any other suggestions. Thanks :)

Comment: 1.Try checking if the label is not nil.    2. Or use self.yourLabel.setNeedsDisplay()     3. Put all the UI actions inside a function and then call it. You are first adding the label as a subview and then setting the text. I dont think thats will be the best way to go around doing it.